# Spring MVC : showing a link in the error message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the following snippet of code in the Validator which basically is used to show an error message. In the error message I would like to show a link by sending it as a parameter in the error message.

```
if (user != null && formData.getUserId()== null) {          
    errors.rejectValue("email", "email.already.exists",new Object[]{"Link "},null);
    return;
}
```

I am unable to get the desired error message on the JSP page . The error is rendered like a string 
and is not converted to HTML code. Please help.

Thank you 
Manu

Answer (score 4):

`<form:errors>` has an `escapeHtml` attribute:

```
<form:errors escapeHtml = "false" ... />
```

Note, however, that this may cause undesired behaviour if other error messages displayed by this tag should be escaped.

Comment: I this case I got  {{Attribute escapeHtml invalid for tag errors according to TLD}}

Answer (score 3):

The attribute is now `htmlEscape`.  See [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.errors) for reference.

So, if you use `<form:errors htmlEscape="false" ... />` then you can have html in the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error variable should only be a string. In your JSP, enclose that string with whatever HTML markup you would like.